# Рисование линии, закраска треугольника

Tags: c++, 3d

Недавно появилось желание написать свой мини 3D движок. Знания математики есть, хотелось бы не пользуясь практически никакими библиотеками, кроме виндосовских, написать его с нуля. Мне нужны операторы рисования точки, и рисования линии на форме или экране, желательно максимально близкие к командам, посылаемым видеокарте. И, если такая есть, то команда закрашивания треугольника)
Буду благодарен за предоставление любой ссылки и информации.

Comment: Вы же пишите, что не хотите пользоваться библиотеками. Зачем вам функции рисования?

Comment: почти не хочу пользоваться.
если в стандартных нет рисования, то можно уж и библиотеки использовать, но хотелось бы самые простые команды без всяких обработок, работающие максимально быстро

Comment: Максимально быстро работает то, что максимально близко к железу, а это драйвера. После драйверов идут уже DirectDraw и OpenGL, а там уже есть все что вы хотите сделать) Дальше WinAPI и так далее.

Comment: а есть возможность получить доступ к работе драйверов?) с драйверами раньше на сях не работал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ИМХО, это тот случай, когда свой велосипед не будет работать лучше уже готового. Функции того же OpenGL реализованы на уровне драйверов, например проецирование фактически выполняет сама видеокарта. А вообще можно погуглить на тему [рендеринга](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%ED%E4%E5%F0%E8%ED%E3). Если интересует конкретно проецирование, можно посмотреть здесь: [Перспективные преобразования](http://www.sernam.ru/book_mm3d.php?id=66).

Comment: Спасибо, мне не важно что он лучше. Я обычно в итоге как раз и прихожу к лучшему велосипеду, но своими усилиями, иногда с подсказками конечно. Зато после этого полностью знаю устройство этого велосипеда и никогда его не забуду. Конечно, самонадеянно думать, что я смогу создать OpenGL, который делал не один человек не один год, но мне надо в этом покопаться)
Поищу по рендерингу, спасибо за помощь, за ссылки!

Answer (score 0):

Используй либо OpenGL, либо Direct3D (без D3DX). Если видеодрайвер установлен, то ничего таскать с собой не придётся.

Если принципиально не хочешь использовать ничего кроме WinAPI, гугли GDI. Но он медленный, потому что софтварный, а писать 3D на нём неудобно.

Лично я рекомендую использовать OpenGL. Изучить его можно по "OpenGL суперкниге".

Comment: Спасибо, я просто начал работать с OpenGL, мне стало интересно, как он проецирует 3х мерную сцену на плоскость и вообще как всё устроенно. И мне стало интересно написать свой движок, который будет работать по-другому. Я знаю что на глубоком уровне OpenGL и DirectX весьма похожи.
Нежелание использовать сторонние библиотеки вызвано тем, что там много лишнего уже реализовано.
Хотелось бы иметь самые простейшие команды и создать всё самому.
Наверное, я плохо в вопросе объяснил чего хочу)
И да, я люблю изобретать велосипед. Я так гораздо лучше понимаю устройство тех или иных вещей.